# mysql table japanese characters in json col look like \u95a2\u6771

Tags: mysql

Normally, I don't have this kind a problem, my database collation is `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` and I can display japanese characters without a problem. But in my notification table when I store `json` data it displays like below.

[image]

I searched a bit and changed my Laravel database config like below.

```
 'charset' => 'utf8',
 'collation' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

And also I changed DB table collation to `utf8_general_ci` too... But still same problem.

### UPDATED

And when I inserting DB my data, I tried to use this `json_encode($database,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)` as well... like below. But no effects all... still char problem in the table json format.

```
allestates::insertGetId($database);
$user = User::first();
$user->notify(new EstateNews(json_encode($database,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE)));
$this->line('DATA SAVED.');
```

Is there way to fix this problem?